# Filtrar dados no BindingSource sem o uso de %

Tags: vb.net

Eu carrego os dados de um banco de dados em um BindingSource e utilizo ele para fazer procuras.

O mesmo está amarrado com um `datagridview`, cujo o qual me retorna os dados procurados, no momento estou utilizando o LIKE para fazer essas procuras, porém ele não está me agradando veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
ValorProcurado = Par*3/4*3          >>>>> aqui estou tentando procurar um parafuso 3/4x3 na minha tabela

Dim Tabela As New BindingSource

Dim Valores() As String = Split(ValorProcurado, "*")
Dim Valor As String = ""
Dim ValorFiltro As String = ""


For Each Valor In Valores
            If ValorFiltro = "" Then
                ValorFiltro = "'%" & Valor & "%'"
            Else
                ValorFiltro = ValorFiltro & " AND " & ColunaFiltro & " LIKE '%" & Valor & "%'"
            End If
Next

Tabela.Filter = "Descricao LIKE " & ValorFiltro
```

Do jeito que estou fazendo eu consigo procurar os valores, mas não é procurado na sequencia em que coloquei, eu queria nesse exemplo acima que o datagridview me retorna-se itens que comecem com "par" e que depois seguindo a sequencia tivessem "3/4" e depois tivessem "3".

Comment: Isso é VB?.....

Comment: sim desculpa....

Comment: Essa parte aqui `ValorProcurado = Par*3/4*3 ` não deveria ser uma string, tipo: `ValorProcurado = "Par*3/4*3"`

Comment: Sim, ja está desse jeito, o código está funcionando, mas conforme expliquei eu queria que a procura fosse sequencial e não do jeito que está

Comment: A cláusula _WHERE_ não deveria ter _OR_ ao invés de _AND_? Porque assim está a limitar muito o espectro dos resultados.